# Diagonalisation of a Matrix with Distinct Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have this Matrix $A$. I want to diagonalise it so that $D = P^{-1}AP$.

$A =\begin{pmatrix} 6 & -2 & 2  \\ -2 & 6 & 2 \\ 4 & 4 & 4\end{pmatrix}$

I found the Eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 0 , \lambda_2 = 8, \lambda_3 =8$. Since the Eigenvalues are not distinct, is my Matrix Diagonalisable? Since my Matrix A has an Eigenvalue with Multiciplity 2, this means that 2 Eigen Vectors will be Linearly Dependent, and therefore my Matrix is not Diagonalisable? Is there any ***simple*** way to get around this.

If someone have an example of the Diagonalisation of a Matrix when going around this that would be great!

Comment: My Matrix is not Symmetric, look at lower right corner and upper right corners...

Comment: alright. However, after subtracting $8I,$ the resulting matrix really is rank one. The vectors annihilated by it make a two dimensional space, there are two independent vectors as a basis of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite not being symmetric the matrix is diagonalizable.  To flesh out Will's comment, 
$$ A-8I = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 
-2&-2&2 \\ -2&-2&2 \\ 4&4&-4 \end{array} \right] $$ is clearly rank one. Since it maps into $R^3$ it must have a two-dimensional kernel. Two easy vectors seen to span it are $(1,-1,0)$ and $(1,0,1)$.  The trouble with using them to diagonalized $A$ is that they are not orthogonal. However, we can use the Gram-Schmidt procedure to produce two orthogonal vectors spanning Ker$(A)$.

Essentially if $v_i$ are our vectors we subtract the projection of $v_2$ onto $v_1$ from $v_2$ to get an $8$-eigenvector normal to $v_1$. With our example, this gives $v_1 =(1,-1,0)$ and $v_2=(1/2,1/2,1)$. Use these two vectors in addition to the $0$-eigenvector to produce the columns of your matrix $P$.